# RxJs subscription drops after one flatMap due to error

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have the following fiddle (simplified version of some code I have).

https://jsfiddle.net/9uau0ya4/

```
const subject = new Rx.Subject();

const subscription = subject.flatMap(Rx.Observable.fromPromise).subscribe((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});

const promise1 = new Promise((resolve) => {
  resolve(1);
});

const promise2 = new Promise((resolve) => {
  resolve(2);
});

const promise3 = new Promise((resolve) => {
  resolve(3);
});
subject.onNext(promise1);
subject.onNext(promise2);
subject.onNext(promise3);
```

When I run that fiddle I expect 1, 2, 3 to be logged to the console. What happens is 1 is logged fine, but the next two onNext() calls on the subject show an error 
    Uncaught ( in promise ) TypeError: self._s.schedule is not a function

I've tried the above with native promises and q.js promises and both seem to show the same. I've looked through the docs but I can't seem to come up with an answer to whats going on here.

Comment: Also, If I place a breakpoint in the spot where the scheduler (_s) property (line 2435 of rx.all) it appears that the _s property (which is supposed to be the scheduler) is set to an integer value that increments per promise plopped on the stream. (it doesn't matter what value I resolve in the promise, it gets incremented with every promise in the stream)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be an issue with function binding. If you check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fgwj8t0a/), it works fine. The difference between the two is that in the last the `this` is clearly bound to `Rx.Observable`.

I can't seem to find an article which explains this properly but basically if you an object with properties, `obj.a.b(x)` and b is a function, that is evaluated and `this` for `b` is bound to `obj.a`. But if you do `obj.a.b` without calling the function, then the evaluation returns a function expression, and I don't remember what the `this` of that function be.

```
const subject = new Rx.Subject();
const fromPromise = function (x) {
return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(x);
}

  const subscription = subject.flatMap(fromPromise).subscribe((value) => {
    console.log(value);
  });

  const promise1 = new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(1);
  });

  const promise2 = new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(2);
  });

  const promise3 = new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(3);
  });
  subject.onNext(promise1);
  subject.onNext(promise2);
  subject.onNext(promise3);
```

Comment: That did work. I thought it might be a context issue but that fact that the scheduler was there the first time through had me perplexed...

Comment: Thank you, the explanation helped.